# Xamarin: How do I apply the following android theme to my activity at runtime?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android

I have the following activity which specifies the theme as an attribute

```
[Activity(Label = "PermissionsActivity", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar")]
public class PermissionsActivity: Activity
```

This works well, but how can I apply the same at runtime? Maybe by calling `SetTheme` in `OnCreate`. I can see SetTheme accepts a resource id integer. I'm having a hard time finding the corresponding Xamarin.Android constant for the aforementioned theme. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your theme in `style.xml` file under Resource folder than access it from resource as `int`

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
</style>
```

Setting in activity

```
this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MyTheme);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your onCreate Method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Call setTheme before creation of any(!) View.
 setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dark);

// ...
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

[For reference check this Link](http://www.anddev.org/applying_a_theme_to_your_application-t817.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you add some theme in any folder under the resources of an android project what Visual studio does is it creates a corresponding int value inside the ResourceDesigner.cs file under the resources folder.

Now in Runtime when you need to add these to your code they are available as follows:

- If the resource is a style then it is available in `Resource.Style.YourResourceName`
- If the resource is a dimension then it is available in `Resource.Dimen.YourResourceName`
- If the resource is a string then it is available in `Resource.String.YourResourceName`
- If the resource is an image under the drawable folder then it is available in `Resource.Drawable.YourResourceName`
- If the resource is an image under the mipmap folder then it is available in `Resource.Mipmap.YourResourceName`, And so on and so forth.

Note: These properties are always an integer.

In your case since it is a theme(which is basically a style)

Hence you can get it like this in an Activity:

```
this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MyTheme);
```

And in a Fragment something like this :

```
this.Activity.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MyTheme);
```

Hope this helps,

Revert in case of queries.